# When there are many hands in an image, what is Mediapipe's policy of enumerating them?

Tags: enumeration, mediapipe

When there are many hands in an image, what is Mediapipe's policy of enumerating them? Say there are 4 hands in the image. They will be given numbers 0,1,2,3. which hand will be given which number, and how is it determined?

I want to write a code that treats each hand differently. How do I know which hand related to which data inferred by Mediapipe?